# How to style a layer from console?

Tags: qgis, python-2.7

I am new to the QGIS python console.
I am trying to load a raster layer from the console, set the crs and a specific style from a qml file.

```
layerPath = os.path.join(raster_dir,raster_name)
fileInfo = QtCore.QFileInfo(layerPath)
baseName = fileInfo.baseName()
layer = QgsRasterLayer(layerPath, baseName)
```

I would like to set up the projection info and then load it to QGIS

```
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
```

I do have a grey raster on the windows. How can I set up the qml file to load ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 18, accepted):

use [QgsMapLayer::loadNamedStyle](http://www.qgis.org/api/classQgsMapLayer.html#a6b117fdc1a090d014374a6981405d1ea)

```
uri = "/home/user/style.qml"
layer.loadNamedStyle(uri)
```

Comment: Thank for your help, Unfortunatly, it does'nt not work. How shall write the uri ?

Comment: Thank you for your help, However I cannot manage to get it working.When I run the following command

Comment: Thank you for your help, However I cannot manage to get it working.When I run the following command `uri = "file:///home/renaud/palette.qml";layer.loadNamedStyle(uri)`   I get the error message : Style not found in databased. Thank for your help ? How do I jump line in this post ?

Comment: looks like `theUri` is a bit misleading - using the plain filename should work (ie. `/home/renaud/palette.qml`)

Comment: Thank You, It is working fine now. One more time, keep it simple is the best way !