# Applying single-band color map from file using pyQGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, pyqgis, color-ramp

I am importing a number of rasters using the python console in QGIS 2.8. I would like to color them all using the same color map, which I have saved to a file. I would like to do this using python so that I don't have to navigate the gui for each file (i.e., right click on the layer -> properties -> style; Render type=Singleband psuedocolor; load color map from file).

My current approach is to follow the [Using Raster Layers](http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/raster.html) tutorial. However, I just read the contents of my color map file and convert it to the input of setColorRampItemList().

Here's my code so far

```
from qgis.core import QgsRasterLayer
from qgis.core import QgsColorRampShader
from PyQt4.QtCore import QFileInfo
from PyQt4.QtGui import QColor

def GetColorRampItemListFromText(file_contents):
    file_contents = file_contents.split('\n')[2:] # get rid of header
    file_contents = [ map(int,line.split(',')[0:4]) for line in file_contents ] 
    lst = [ QgsColorRampShader.ColorRampItem(line[0], QColor(line[1],line[2],line[3])) for line in file_contents ]
    return lst

raster = "D:\\example.tif"

fileInfo = QFileInfo(raster)
path = fileInfo.filePath()
baseName = fileInfo.baseName()

layer = QgsRasterLayer(path, baseName)
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(layer)


file_contents = """# QGIS Generated Color Map Export File
INTERPOLATION:INTERPOLATED
0,0,0,0,255,0.000000
1,0,255,0,255,1.000000
2,0,170,0,255,2.000000
3,170,85,0,255,3.000000
4,243,205,255,255,4.000000
5,0,255,255,255,5.000000
6,255,255,0,255,6.000000
7,255,255,255,255,7.000000
8,255,0,0,255,8.000000
9,0,0,255,255,9.000000
10,130,133,123,255,10.000000
11,11,86,29,255,11.000000
12,255,0,255,255,12.000000
13,0,0,0,255,13.000000
14,255,174,0,255,14.000000"""
lst = GetColorRampItemListFromText(file_contents)

fcn = QgsColorRampShader()
fcn.setColorRampType(QgsColorRampShader.INTERPOLATED)


fcn.setColorRampItemList(lst)
shader = QgsRasterShader()
shader.setRasterShaderFunction(fcn)
renderer = QgsSingleBandPseudoColorRenderer(layer.dataProvider(), 1, shader)
layer.setRenderer(renderer)


layer.dataProvider().reloadData()
layer.triggerRepaint()
```

My question is either:

1. Why is my code not rendering the color table?
2. Is there an easier way to apply a color table from a file?

EDIT:
The reason it wasn't rendering has something to do with `layer.dataProvider().reloadData()`. Removing it works as expected.

For what it's worth, Here's another similar question and answer: [Assigning Color Ramp using PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/118775/assigning-color-ramp-using-pyqgis)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really know how you got the CSV color ramp so I can't perfectly answer but you should adopt the following couple of functions

```
layer.saveNamedStyle("your_raster_style.qml")
```

and imagining a `layer1` raster file

```
layer1.loadNamedStyle("your_raster_style.qml")
```

Not need to manually copy the style IMO.

Comment: I think this essentially solves the problem I had - it's definitely a lot more concise. I got the color table from a colleague. The only downside to this solution is I initially have to manually import the color table and export the style, so that I can apply the style in python. But that's not too much labor :) Thanks.